# Arduino Adafruit playground: Adafruit_CPlay_LIS3DH.cpp:27:35: fatal error: Adafruit_CPlay_LIS3DH.h: No such file or directory

Tags: adafruit

I've tried installing the Arduino Adafruit playground but came across the same error.

```
sketch\src\Libraries\Adafruit_Circuit_Playground\utility\Adafruit_CPlay_LIS3DH.cpp:27:35: fatal error: Adafruit_CPlay_LIS3DH.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Adafruit_CPlay_LIS3DH.h>

                                   ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
```

I don't really know what else I can try. I've tried reinstalling the library and 
different versions of the Arduino IDE but is doesn't seem to work.

IDE version: 1.8.7

Playground version: 1.8.1

Comment: the error start with "sketch\src\". where is your "Libraries" folder located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry completely forgot about this post. Apparently I had a folder in my project with the playground library that wasn't updated. When I removed this folder everything worked fine.